# Transformer-XL architecture

Tags: neural-network, transformer

I am a bit perplex from the transformer-XL architecture that is claimed to solve the issue of context fragmantation. I probably understood it wrong but it looks like all the transformer-XL is doing, is being 2 times larger than the normal one, and that you translate at each iterations. Plus a fancy new way of doing positional encoding.

Am I interpreting it wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your interpretation does not focus on the right places.

First, let's understand where the predecessor idea of Transformer XL in LSTM Language Models: **Truncated Back-Propagation Through Time (TBPTT)**. In LSTM Language Models, the training data text is concatenated into a single very long sequence. From this sequence, we create training batches in a way that for batch $k$, the text sequence at position $i$ is the continuation of the sequence at the same position in batch $k-1$. When training the LSTM, the last hidden states generated at batch $k-1$ were used as initial hidden states when processing batch $k$. The gradients were not propagated through batches, only the values of the hidden states. This allowed the LSTM to be able to profit from unlimited-length context.

The same idea cannot be directly applied to Transformers, as there is not a single hidden state, but as many hidden states as the number of tokens in the sequence times the number of layers.

[TransformerXL](http://arxiv.org/abs/1901.02860) solves that by incorporating all those hidden states from the previous batch into the computation of the new batch, without propagating the gradients (see figure below from the original article).

[image]

This, however, poses a problem in how the positional information in managed in the Transformer, as the positional embeddings encode absolute positions. Therefore, the authors reformulated them to be relative.

Therefore, **the main advantage of Transformer XL over vanilla Transformer LMs is that it can profit from unlimited-length context.**

Note that Transformer XL is "only" a Language Model, it does not translate, just computes probabilities of the next token based on the previous ones.